# Unexpected page redirection from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, twitter, facebook-opengraph

I was testing a page with Twitter Cards and for the provided URL (I'm simplifying the URL but the output is valid) using [Twitters card preview tool](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator):

```
https://example.net/hello/test-page/
```

It was pulling the card but with this warning:

```
INFO:  Page fetched successfully
INFO:  16 metatags were found
INFO:  twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found
INFO:  Card loaded successfully
WARN:  this card is redirected to http://example.net/hello/test-page/
```

The only difference here is that the HTTPS has been switched to HTTP. It is not just Twitter, but FB and LinkedIn too.

Using [LinkedIn's link preview tool](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/), it similarly reported:

```
URL redirect trail
1   301 Redirect  https://example.net/hello/test-page/
2   200 Success  http://example.net/hello/test-page/
```

And with [Facebooks link debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/):

```
Response Code
200

Fetched URL
https://example.net/hello/test-page/

Canonical URL   
http://example.net/hello/test-page/

Redirect Path   
Input URL -> https://example.net/hello/test-page/
301 HTTP Redirect -> http://example.net/hello/test-page/
og:url Meta Tag -> https://example.net/hello/test-page/
```

So... I check the source of the generated web page and I can confirm:

All OG and Twitter Card related META and LINK tags are not using "http". They are all "https". The canonical LINK tag is also using "https".

If I manually go to the "http" version of the URL in the browser, it redirects me immediately to the "https" version.

Can anyone explain why this might happen, and places where I should start to dig?

One last example, when I run this curl command in Terminal, it also seems fine:

```
curl -sLD - https://example.net/hello/test-page/ -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'

HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 16:27:28 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 16:23:11 GMT
cache-control: max-age=43, must-revalidate
x-nananana: Batcache-Hit
vary: Cookie
x-ac: 2.ord _atomic_dca
```

(In case its relevant; this is a WordPress site but I have no unusual plugins running)

Answer (score 0):

The 'issue' was with hosting provider, in this case Pressable, and because we used Lets Encrypt for SSL certs.

Here are the relevant parts from the support chat:

> The reason that this occurs is because on WordPress.com, there wasn't
> always free SSL certificates via Let's Encrypt. So, in relation to
> Facebook, for example, posts that displayed a Facebook like button
> with counts would have a canonical URL at Facebook like
> http://myblog.com/some/post. Turning on SSL and 301 redirecting the
> http:// version of that page to https:// would wipe out those
> like/share counts because Facebook sees the exact same URL with a
> different protocol as two distinct things.
>
> So, the implementation had to serve SSL certificates and force SSL for
> the millions of sites that were now going to have a free Let’s Encrypt
> SSL certificate, but also needed to give these crawlers a way to
> access the content over http.
>
> When doing the Pressable implementation of Let’s Encrypt, a lot of it
> was copied from WordPress.com, and it was not incorrect to do so.
> Pressable also didn’t always have free SSL certificates. If we started
> to force the redirection of sites that were always http to https that
> had “like” buttons and share counts, those counts would have been
> lost.

Can't say I'm thrilled with the answer.